# How to get a url after returning the view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, actionresult

I am new to MVC4, I am using more then one form in one View. When i am posting the form i am getting all the formcollecion values in controller. When i am returning the different view also, its working fine. My problem is after returning view, the url showing that post method name.when i try to refresh this page its showing error.

Initially the url was : **Admin/Activities**
after posting the form : **Admin/UpdateActivity**
I need url like this after returning the view : **Admin/Activities**
how to get it, Please help me. Thanks in advance.

I dont have any separate view for this ActionResult. This is my code:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UpdateActivity(FormCollection coll)
        {
            ................
            ViewBag.updateAlert = "Activity updated sucessfully";
            return View("Activities");
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateActivity", "Admin", FormMethod.Post,new { @id = "formID" }))
```

Change your form attribute as it. It will automatically return to the view **Activities**.

Note: if your form on Admin/Activities.

Comment: No, Its not working. Still its showing the same url like : Admin/UpdateActivity

Answer (score 0):

After updating the record,you can Redirect to that action,instead of returning the same view again, and instead of  **ViewBag** you will have to use **TempData** as **ViewBag** will be `null` after redirecting:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UpdateActivity(FormCollection coll)
        {
            ................
            TempData["updateAlert"] = "Activity updated sucessfully";
            return RedirectToAction("Activities","Admin");
        }
```

Comment: But if i use RediectoToAction, i am not getting the viewbag value

Comment: you have to use TempData in this case TempData will be accessible there

Comment: You need to go with @Vikram's  answer.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad in case you need to show other page on submission then u can use RediectoToAction method.

Comment: @Sarbanjeet i changed it, Now also its not working. its showing the same url : Admin/UpdateActivity

Comment: @user3336505 its depends on which view you are using it.

Put this form tag in activities view and update form controller name and actions name (UpdateActivity) with Form Method.

Comment: Do you summiting by traditional way or using AJAX ?

Comment: No, By by normal html form submit like <input type="submit">